# Using Pandas to dynamically replace values found in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataset looks like this:

| Car | Make | Model | Engine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota Rav 4 8cyl6L | Toyota |  | 8cyl6L |
| Mitsubishi Eclipse 2.1T | Mitsubishi |  | 2.1T |
| Monster Gravedigger 25Lsc | Monster |  | 25Lsc |

The data was clearly concatenated from Make + Model + Engine at some point but the car Model was not provided to me.

I've been trying to use Pandas to say that if we take Car, replace instances of Make with a nothing, replace instances of Engine with nothing, then trim the spaces around the result, we will have Model.

| Car | Make | Model | Engine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toyota Rav 4 8cyl6L | Toyota | Rav 4 | 8cyl6L |
| Mitsubishi Eclipse 2.1T | Mitsubishi | Eclipse | 2.1T |
| Monster Gravedigger 25Lsc | Monster | Gravedigger | 25Lsc |

There's something I'm doing wrong when I'm trying to reference another column in this manner.

```
df['Model'] = df['Car'].str.replace(df['Make'],'')
```

gives me an error of "unhashable type: 'Series'". I'm guessing I'm accidentally inputting the entire 'Make' column.

At every row I want to make a different substitution using data from other columns in that row. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use:

```
df['Model']=df.apply(lambda x: x['Car'].replace(x['Make'],"").replace(x['Engine'],""),axis=1)
print(df)
'''
                         Car        Make          Model  Engine
0        Toyota Rav 4 8cyl6L      Toyota         Rav 4   8cyl6L
1    Mitsubishi Eclipse 2.1T  Mitsubishi       Eclipse     2.1T
2  Monster Gravedigger 25Lsc     Monster   Gravedigger    25Lsc
'''
```

Comment: This worked great. For this exact situation I tacked on .strip() to the end df['Model']=df.apply(lambda x: x['Car'].replace(x['Make'],"").replace(x['Engine'],"").strip(),axis=1)

Answer (score 1):

A `regex` proposition using [**`re.sub`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) :

```
import re

df['Model'] = [re.sub(f'{b}|{c}', '', a) for a,b,c in zip(df['Car'], df['Make'], df["Engine"])]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

                         Car        Make          Model  Engine
0        Toyota Rav 4 8cyl6L      Toyota         Rav 4   8cyl6L
1    Mitsubishi Eclipse 2.1T  Mitsubishi       Eclipse     2.1T
2  Monster Gravedigger 25Lsc     Monster   Gravedigger    25Lsc
```